# "ObjectId: New" is causing a Nil value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm retrieving data from Parse and attempting to get the ObjectId of `Post`. I can pull the data out from Parse fine, yet when I try to assign that data into a variable the objectId suddenly reads out `ObjectId: New`.

This is causing my app to crash! What is this error?

[image: objectId is present from Parse Query]

Note: the readouts are of two different posts, but the error is the same. Present when retrieving data from Parse, "New" when assigning it.

[image: objectId: New is here]

Code retrieving `post` object:

```
    GetPostsForClass.getPostsForClass({ (result:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        let posts = result as? [Post] ?? []
        print(posts)
        completionBlock(posts)
        }, classroom: self.classroom!, range: range)

}
```

...

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell") as! ClassPostTableViewCell

    let post = timelineComponent.content[indexPath.row]
    post.setPost()
    cell.post = post
    //cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

}

Code I use to attempt assigning ObjectId string:

```
    func setPost(){
    ...
    self.objectId = self["objectId"] as? String

    ...
    post.setPost()
    print("OUTER the objectId is \(post.objectId)")
```

The print readout is `NIL`

Comment: Where are you creating the post object?  You haven't shown that code.  Also you typically don't need to use the objectid in parse. If you have a pointer column type you can just assign an instance of PFObject

Comment: thanks for the reply - added some code. I might end up doing that.